# io exception in openInputStream in Nokia 5800

Tags: java-me, io, inputstream

I am using the following code to parse XML from server.

```
try {
    //Open http connection
    HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URL);

    resultItem.setLabel("34");
    this.sleep(1000);
    //Initilialize XML parser
    parser = new KXmlParser();
    resultItem.setLabel("38");
    this.sleep(1000);
    resultItem.setLabel("39");
    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.openInputStream());
    System.out.println("Input Sream: "+isr.read());

    resultItem.setLabel("40");
    this.sleep(1000);                
    parser.setInput(isr);

    resultItem.setLabel("42");
    this.sleep(1000);

    parser.nextTag();
    resultItem.setLabel("46");
    this.sleep(1000);

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "login");
    resultItem.setLabel("50");
    this.sleep(1000);

    //Iterate through our XML file
    while (parser.nextTag() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) 
    {
        readXMLData(parser);
    }
    resultItem.setLabel("57");
    this.sleep(1000);

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "login");
    parser.next();
    resultItem.setLabel("62");
    this.sleep(1000);
    resultItem.setLabel("64");
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT, null, null);
    resultItem.setLabel("");
    this.sleep(1000);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    resultItem.setLabel("Error:");
    resultItem.setText( e.toString());
}
```

It works fine in `Nokia 2700`, but shows IO exception in  `InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.openInputStream());`. Why it is happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: What is the detail of the exception. Any additional messages?

Comment: May I know the reason for using `this.sleep(1000)` at many places?

Comment: I was checking that exactly where problem occurs in device.That's why I am using this.sleep(1000) and set value to stringItem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't send request. And let is why you can't read request )

Try this:

```
HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URL);
rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
if(rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
// all your code
}
```